# Is exponential function strongly convex?

Tags: convex-analysis

Assume $x \in \mathbb{R}$. In the wiki page, one property of strongly convex functions $f(x)$ is that it satisfies:

$f''(x)\geq m > 0~\forall x$ with with parameter $m > 0$.

Given $f(x) =e^x$, since $lim_{x\to -\infty} f''(x) = 0$ does this mean that exponential is not strongly convex?

Comment: I think it's strongly convex on compact intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the Wikipedia page on [Convex function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function):

> The exponential function $f(x)=e^x$ is convex.  It is also strictly convex, since $f''(x)=e^x>0$, but it is not strongly convex since the second derivative can be arbitrarily close to zero.  More generally, the function $g(x)=e^{f(x)}$ is [logarithmically convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_convex_function) if $f$ is a convex function. The term *superconvex* is sometimes used instead.

Comment: As $x\to -\infty$ can you find such a $m$?

Comment: Okay, I get your point now.  Please see my revised answer, @AdamI.